# How do I format numbers as decimals in NextJS

Tags: javascript, css, next.js

I'm working on a basic website using NextJS, my code is like this

```
products: [
 {
   brand: 'example',
   price: 10000,
 },
...
],
```

How do I change the `10000` to `10,000`.

Comment: does this answer your question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `toLocaleString()` to format the number with commas like this:

```js
var a = 10000000;
console.log(a.toLocaleString())
```

```js
var obj = {products: [
 {
   brand: 'example',
   price: 10000,
 }
]
}

obj.products[0].price = obj.products[0].price.toLocaleString()

console.log(obj)
```